# Determine the interval of convergence of the series:

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sin(\frac{\pi}{k})(x-1)^k$

I used the ratio test to reach:

$\vert(x-1)\vert\lim_{n\to \infty} \vert \frac {\sin(\frac{\pi}{k+1})}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{k})}\vert\lt1$

but I don't know where to go from here

Answer (score 1):

We take the limit as $n$, not $x$, goes to $\infty$. This is because we want to find the radius of convergence of $x$, and if $x\to\infty$, then $R\to\infty$ which is not what we want. The limit of $a_n$ is indeterminant, so we use L'Hôpital's rule with respect to $n$

$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin{\frac{\pi}{n+1}}}{\sin{\frac{\pi}{n}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\cos{\frac{\pi}{n+1}}}{\cos{\frac{\pi}{n}}}\frac{\frac{-\pi}{(n+1)^2}}{\frac{-\pi}{n^2}}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\cos{\frac{\pi}{n+1}}}{\cos{\frac{\pi}{n}}}\right)\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\frac{-\pi}{(n+1)^2}}{\frac{-\pi}{n^2}}\right)$$

The limit of the cosines is $1$ and

$$\displaystyle\frac{\frac{-\pi}{(n+1)^2}}{\frac{-\pi}{n^2}}=\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^2}$$

Comment: How would you prove that the limit of the cosines is 1?

Comment: As n approaches infinity, the argument approaches 0, cos(0) = 1, and 1/1 = 1. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note that

$$\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac {\sin(\frac{\pi}{k+1})}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{k})}=\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{k}{k+1}\frac {\sin(\frac{\pi}{k+1})}{\frac{\pi}{k+1}}\frac {\frac{\pi}{k}}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{k})}\to 1$$

then

$$\vert x-1\vert\ \lim_{k\to \infty} \frac {\sin(\frac{\pi}{k+1})}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{k})} \to \vert x-1\vert$$

Answer (score 0):

From what you have gotten,
the sum converges for
$|x-1| < 1$
or
$0 < x < 2$.

The only uncertainty
is at the endpoints.
The key to these
is noticing that
$\sin(\frac{\pi}{k})
\to \frac{\pi}{k}
$
as $k \to \infty$.
In particular,
if $0 \le x \le \pi/2$,
$\frac{2x}{\pi}
\le \sin(x)
\le x$.

At
$x=2$,
the sum is
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sin(\frac{\pi}{k})
$
and this diverges because
$\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(\frac{\pi}{k})
\ge \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\pi}{k}\frac{2}{\pi}
= 2\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}
$
and this is the well-known
diverging harmonic series.

At $x=0$,
the sum is
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\sin(\frac{\pi}{k})
$
and this converges because
it is an alternating series
of decreasing terms.

(added after looking 
at Matt Werner's answer)

I realize that
we have to prove that
$ r_k
=\frac {\sin(\frac{\pi}{k+1})}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{k})}
\to 1$.

First of all,
$r_k < 1$
since sine is monotonic decreasing.

There are a number of ways
to show that
$r_k \to 1$.
One way is using
$\sin'(0) = 1$.

I will try another.

By the mean value theorem,
$\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)
=h\cos(x+c)
$
where
$0 \le c \le h$.
Therefore
$\sin(\frac{\pi}{k})-\sin(\frac{\pi}{k+1})
=\frac{\pi}{k(k+1)}\cos(\frac{\pi}{k}+c)
\le\frac{\pi}{k(k+1)}
$.

Therefore,
since
$\sin(x) \ge \frac{2x}{\pi}$,

$\begin{array}\\
1-\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{k+1})}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{k})}
&\le\frac{\pi}{k(k+1)\sin(\frac{\pi}{k})}\\
&\le\frac{\pi}{k(k+1)\frac{2}{k}}\\
&\le\frac{\pi}{2(k+1)}\\
\text{so}\\
\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{k+1})}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{k})}
&\ge 1-\frac{\pi}{2(k+1)}\\
\end{array}
$